# Solving differential equation using Fourier Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I have the following differential equation I need to solve:

$x'(t) + 2x(t) = u(t)$

So here's how I proceed:

$F^{-1} (x'(t)) + 2 F^{-1} (x(t))  =F^{-1} ( u(t))$

$2\pi if   \hat{x}(f) + 2\hat{x}(f)  = \frac{1}{2} \delta(f) + \frac{1}{2 \pi if }  $

$\hat{x}(f)  (2 + 2 i \pi f) = \frac{1}{2} \delta(f) + \frac{1}{2 \pi if }$

$\hat{x}(f) = \frac{\delta(f)}{2 (2 + 2 i \pi f)} +  \frac{1}{2\pi i f (2 + 2 i \pi f)}$

So now:

$x(t) = F^{-1} (\frac{\delta(f)}{2 (2 + 2 i \pi f)}) +  F^{-1}(\frac{1}{2\pi i f (2 + 2 i \pi f)})$

And that's how far I got. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Is there a reason to use the Fourier transform over the Laplace transform here?

Comment: @Math1000 The excercise is set to be resolved using Fourier transform, otherwise I wouldn't mind.